# SQL Server - Divide a dataset to same size groups with random rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Have a base dataset which is a set of ID's, F.E.

```
000
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

and a keys dataset

```
1 - 20
2 - 40
3 - 40
```

The result should be a random pairing of the base dataset with the keys dataset according to the defined percentage, meaning 20% will recieve 1, 40% will recieve 2 and 40% will recieve 3

F.E. - first run

```
000 - 1
111 - 2
222 - 3
333 - 1
444 - 2
555 - 3
666 - 2
777 - 3
888 - 2
999 - 3
```

second run

```
000 - 2
111 - 3
222 - 2
333 - 3
444 - 2
555 - 3
666 - 1
777 - 3
888 - 2
999 - 1
```

etc.

Using SQL server 2014

Thought of solutions that involve loops and cusrors and temp tables but I was wondering if there is a "cleaner" and most probably more efficient solution...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `Numbers` table.

```
;WITH base_dataset
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn
         FROM   (VALUES (000),
                        (111),
                        (222),
                        (333),
                        (444),
                        (555),
                        (666),
                        (777),
                        (888),
                        (999)) tc (ID)),
     keys
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES (1,20),
                        (2,50),
                        (3,30)) tc(val, per)),
     num_gen
     AS (SELECT 1        AS num,
                Count(1) AS cnt
         FROM   base_dataset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT num + 1,
                cnt
         FROM   num_gen
         WHERE  num < cnt)
SELECT Id,val
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY newid()) rn,
               val
        FROM   num_gen n
               JOIN keys k
                 ON n.num <= (k.per/100.0) * cnt) a
       JOIN base_dataset d
         ON d.rn = a.rn
```

I have used `Recursive CTE` to generate numbers you can create a numbers table in database and use it

Comment: Worls like charm !
Will test it on large datasets as well.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()` and a `join`.  The idea is to accumulate the key "values" (whatever the second column is) and then normalize them between 0 and 1.  Do the same for a random row ordering and (essentially) use `between` for mapping between the tables:

```
with k as (
      select k.*,
             sum(val) over (order by id) * 1.0 / sum(sum(val)) over () as cume_sumval
      from keys k
     )
select d.*, k.id
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (order by newid()) - 1 as seqnum,
             count(*) as cnt
      from dataset d
     ) d join
     k
     on seqnum >= (k.cume_sumval - v) * cnt and
        seqnum < (k.cume_sumval) * cnt;
```